# Placing text on CGContext falls off screen

Tags: cocoa-touch, cgcontext

I'm using Core Graphics to create a PDF in my iPad application. I create a CGContext and begin my PDF page, then use CGContextShowTextAtPoint to place an NSString on the page. The PDF gets created, but if the NSString is lengthy, the text will fall off the page.

Does anyone have a suggestion as to how I could easily add lines? Would I need to separate the string and place them individually?

Would appreciate any help!
Ricky.

Answer (score 1):

If you're in a regular CGContext, you can use the UIKit additions to NSString to layout the text in the current graphics context:

```
[@"this is my string" drawInRect:rect
                        withFont:font
                   lineBreakMode:lineBreakMode
                       alignment:alignment];
```

Alternatively, if you need more fine-grained control, you could use CoreText to control individual runs of text, but drawInRect should solve the basic problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and sorry to take so long to reply. I am drawing in a new CGContext, and when I call that line I get lots of "invalid context 0x0" messages in the consoles.

Comment: I eventually found out I needed to push the CGContext I was drawing on. I also ran into some origin problems. I wrote a solution here: http://iphonedevblog.com/code/rotating-upside-down-text-or-images-in-core-graphics/